# python / pandas - how to filter a data frame by a component of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which returns rows with `date` column formatted as `DD.MM.YY`:

```
transactions_by_shop = transactions.groupby('shop_id')
list(transactions_by_shop)
```

yields something like:

```
   | date     | item      | price
01 | 11.09.14 | item_name | 100.45
```

how do I filter `transactions_by_shop` so that `date` must be greater than `09.14`?

Comment: Have a look at `pd.to_datetime()` to make date comparisons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert to str using `dt.strftime`, and then comparison can be done lexicographically:

```
df[df.date.dt.strftime('%m.%y') > '09.14']
```

Edit: a better solution would be to convert “09.14” to datetime and compare.

Comment: Lexicographic comparisons with month before year?  That'll get you intro trouble, no?

Comment: @DSM yeah, on closer inspection this is an extremely poor answer. I’ll rework this when I get the time to... thanks. I think the best solution is to compare datetimes. Will work that in.